# Cannot join 3 table in Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I am retrieving products from codeigniter there are three tables:

1. dg_products
2. dg_rating
3. dg_like

After joining `dg_products` and `dg_rating` is working but I want to get the like status from `dg_like`.

Structure of `dg_like` is:

```
id | P_id | Uid
```

From session I am able to retrieve current logged in user id but cannot retrieve whether that user has liked that particular product or not. Please give any suggestions.

```
public function get_featured()
{
        $this->db->select('dg_products.*, AVG(dg_rating.rating) As averageRating');
        $this->db->from('dg_products');
        $this->db->join('dg_rating', 'dg_products.id = dg_rating.product_id','left');
        $user_info=$this->session->userdata('logged_in');
        $user_id=$user_info['id'];

        if($user_id != '') {
            $this->db->join('dg_like', 'user_id = dg_like.u_id');
        }

        $this->db->where('dg_products.is_featured_prod','1');
        $this->db->group_by("dg_products.id");

        $query = $this->db->get();   

        $result = $query->result();
        return $result; 
}
```

Comment: In the second join what table holds the `user_id` column used in ` 'user_id = dg_like.u_id'`. Try adding the table name before `user_id`.

Comment: have a look at this: it always helps me to understand joins and to create a plan on how to use them: https://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/

Answer (score 0):

According to the info you provide, you're joining using a non-existing field

If dg_like's structure is

> id | P_id | Uid

the join statement should be

```
 $this->db->join('dg_like', 'user_id = dg_like.Uid');
```

I'd go even further and recommend you make it a `LEFT JOIN` so the output of the query contains all rows, regardless of being liked or not:

```
 $this->db->join('dg_like', 'user_id = dg_like.Uid', 'LEFT');
```

hope that works

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I only have user id column in rating and dg_like table , i want if user does not liked any product then empty liked key should be there.

Comment: That's why you need `LEFT JOIN` (my final example). A regular join will remove the non-liked product-user combinations from the resultset, while the left join will keep them and return a `NULL` value when the product hasn't been liked by the user

Comment: Tried above like this $this->db->join('dg_like', '$user_id = dg_like.Uid', 'LEFT'); but it is not returning rows from dg_like rows where product is being liked by current logged in user.

Answer (score 0):

If you retrieve current logged in user record, according to your table **dg_like** structure is id | P_id | Uid. Here, $user_id is login user id.

```
$this->db->select('dg_products.*, AVG(dg_rating.rating) As averageRating');
$this->db->from('dg_products');
$this->db->join('dg_rating', 'dg_products.id = dg_rating.product_id','left');

if($user_id != '') {
     $this->db->join('dg_like', 'dg_products.id = dg_like.P_id');
}
$this->db->where('dg_like.Uid',$user_id);
$this->db->where('dg_products.is_featured_prod','1');
$this->db->group_by("dg_products.id");
$query = $this->db->get();   
$result = $query->result();
```

I hope your issue is resolved.